# Google Maps Javascript v3 custom controls subclassing standard controls

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to subclass the existing google controls in Javascript API v3?

I want my custom-controls to have the same style and dropdown behaviour. And also, to change when screen sizes change.

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls the controls change, for example, when viewed on an android device.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control objects are not exposed as part of the API. All you have to work with are the DOM nodes which can change without warning. So no, you can't extend the existing controls. You would need to recreate them.